# Google API maps - disappearing content when adding Styled Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been running through the Google Maps javascript example (v3) and have actually been able to create a map using multiple markers (with infoWindow links and info) and some multiple, but simple, Polygon shapes that link out and custom markers.

However, when I began adding in the Styled Map settings, I began to only get partial map information.  I'm a noob as far as javascript goes, but up to this point I've been able to figure out everything else I've ran into by doing some research - but I can't seem to figure this one out.

The working version looks like this: http://www.conleym.com/map/example.html  It's crude, but works.

When I add in the Style Map info, I'm getting this: http://www.conleym.com/map/styled.html

In the interest of space, I'm not posting the code, but will if necessary.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at your javascript errors (in the Javascript console in most browsers, click on the little yellow triangle in IE):

```
Error: styledMap is not defined
Source File: http://www.conleym.com/map/styled.html
Line: 167
```

Then you have additional error with your "mc" variable and your styled map.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_conleym_com_map_styled.html)